# As of Feb 2013, which are the top 5 bitcoin mining pools to join with a good community?

Tags: mining-pools

I'm looking to join a bitcoin mining pool. Which are the top five mining pools with good community support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the blockchain.info's [chart](http://blockchain.info/pools?timespan=4days), as of Feb 2013 the top mining pools apparently are:

- BTC Guild
- 50BTC
- Deepbit
- Slush
- EclipseMC

I can't say for the "good community" since that's obviously quite subjective.

Comment: What about GHash.io? What do you mean "the top mining pools apparently are"? Thanks for the link anyways.

Comment: Hah!!! I just realized that having big mining pools like GHash.io is bad for BitCoin's survival! Don't join GHash :) Sorry I are noobs.